# How to configure proxy setting?

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

I have called webservice which have proxy setup, so I did following code for **http** based webservices:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","10.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","222");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser","xyz");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword","pqr");// base64 password.
```

But when I used same code for **https** based webservices:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","10.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","222");
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser","xyz");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword","pqr");// base64 password.
```

It gives me following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

Or is there any other way to call Https webservice?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this and let me know that helps.. 

System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-proxy-setting-java-setting-proxy-java/
```

Comment: it throws exception Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: